# Setup VLANs for Two SSIDs, Two Different Modems

Tags: networking, vlan

I apologize if any of this is obvious; I am still learning how VLANs work. We have several APs around our building. Our internet provider provides us with a modem for the public network (DCHP enabled, 10.0.0.x) and a modem for our private network (DHCP enabled, 192.168.250.x). I'm having trouble understanding how to setup the VLANs. I would like...

- VLAN 2 - Public Network (Public Modem/Router on LAN 2)
- VLAN 3 - Private Network (Private Modem/Router on LAN 3)
- (I can't seem to make adjustments to VLAN 1. All ports are set to untagged)

We have a switch for our entire building that will be plugged into LAN 1 (Both APs and wired clients are on this switch together). So in the end, I need any wired clients to be on the private network (VLAN 3), wireless clients on public SSID to be on the public network (VLAN 2), and wireless clients on private SSID to be on the private network (VLAN 3). I am struggling with two things.

1. What configuration of VLAN/PVID would I use to accomplish this? (especially which ports are tagged or untagged). Do I make LAN 1 a trunk port? I'm quite lost.
2. The IP addresses of the APs themselves -- should I set them as a static IP in the 192.168.250.x subnet?

Comment: What is your AP model? Does it support multiple VLANs?

Comment: The APs are Unifi AC Lites. They can have up to four SSIDs, each with a separate VLAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is how you can achieve this:

- Connect the AP to a trunk port on the switch, if you can tag the management port as well in the AP then good else have a native vlan on switch as 3(presuming you would want the management of APs in private network). You can set them statically but then you have to reserve these IPs in DHCP otherwise there can be a conflict.
- All the wired clients which are going to be connected in private network to the switch should have the switchports in VLAN 3.
- The ISP provided router which is going to provide IPs in public range should be connected to switch in vlan 2, and the ISP router which is going to provide IPs in private range should be connected to switch on vlan 3 as switch configuration.
- All devices should be DHCP enabled, they will broadcast a request and will get the IP from the router.

Hope this helps!